# r: why is character string showing days and not date when applying as.Date() and origin?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, lubridate

I have

```
> head(p, 10)
   date_contact mr_daterd_fu1
1                  11.10.2012
2                            
3                            
4                            
5    13.12.1994              
6                            
7    20.03.2012    20.03.2012
8    25.08.1999              
9    25.05.2012    25.05.2012
10   19.10.2007
```

I need to replace missing values in `p$date_contact` with `p$mr_daterd_fu1` as in

```
fu1_date = ifelse(is.na(date_contact), 
                  as.Date(mr_daterd_fu1,  format = '%d.%m.%Y'),
                  as.Date(date_contact,  format = '%d.%m.%Y')))
```

But this gives

```
> head(p, 10)
   date_contact mr_daterd_fu1 fu1_date
1                  11.10.2012       NA
2                                   NA
3                                   NA
4                                   NA
5    13.12.1994                   9112
6                                   NA
7    20.03.2012    20.03.2012    15419
8    25.08.1999                  10828
9    25.05.2012    25.05.2012    15485
10   19.10.2007                  13805
```

And

```
> str(p)
'data.frame':   946 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date_contact : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ mr_daterd_fu1: chr  "11.10.2012" "" "" "" ...
 $ fu1_date     : num  NA NA NA NA 9112 ...
```

Why is `p$fu1_date` not displayed `as.Date`?

I tried

```
 p %>% mutate(mr_daterd_fu1 = as.Date(mr_daterd_fu1,  format = '%d.%m.%Y'),
         fu1_date = ifelse(is.na(date_contact), 
                    mr_daterd_fu1,
                    as.Date(date_contact,  format = '%d.%m.%Y', origin=mr_daterd_fu1)))
```

But that did not work.

Expected output:

```
   date_contact mr_daterd_fu1    fu1_date
1                  11.10.2012  2012.10.11
2                                      NA
3                                      NA
4                                      NA
5    13.12.1994                1994.12.13
6                                      NA
7    20.03.2012    20.03.2012  2012.03.20
8    25.08.1999                1999.08.25
9    25.05.2012    25.05.2012  2012.05.25
10   19.10.2007                2007.10.19
```

Data

```
p <- structure(list(date_contact = c("", "", "", "", "13.12.1994", 
"", "20.03.2012", "25.08.1999", "25.05.2012", "19.10.2007"), 
    mr_daterd_fu1 = c("11.10.2012", "", "", "", "", "", "20.03.2012", 
    "", "25.05.2012", "")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `Date` class and use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
p %>%
   mutate(across(c(date_contact, mr_daterd_fu1),
           as.Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")) %>% 
   mutate(ful_date  = coalesce(date_contact, mr_daterd_fu1 ))
```

-output

```
#  date_contact mr_daterd_fu1   ful_date
#1          <NA>    2012-10-11 2012-10-11
#2          <NA>          <NA>       <NA>
#3          <NA>          <NA>       <NA>
#4          <NA>          <NA>       <NA>
#5    1994-12-13          <NA> 1994-12-13
#6          <NA>          <NA>       <NA>
#7    2012-03-20    2012-03-20 2012-03-20
#8    1999-08-25          <NA> 1999-08-25
#9    2012-05-25    2012-05-25 2012-05-25
#10   2007-10-19          <NA> 2007-10-19
```

---

In general, it is better not to use `ifelse` with `Date` class

Comment: Hi akrun. Thank you for your input. I have numerous covariates in my dataset, so `across(everything()..` should not be converted to `as.Date`, only the covariates mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hi @akrun - spin-off question; is it possible to apply your method as something to the effect of: `mutate(across(c("all columns that contain "date_contact", all columns that contain "mr_daterd"), as.Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y"))`?

Comment: You can use `matches("date_contact|mr_daterd")`

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. Received an error on `mutate(across(matches(date_contact | mr_daterd), as.Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y"))`. I think it is because the columns contains `date_contact` and  `mr_daterd` as part of a larger column name, eg. `mr_daterd_fu1`. So it should read something like `all columns that contain date_contact|mr_daterd` - can this be done?

Comment: You need to quote i.e. `mutate(across(matches("date_contact|mr_daterd"), as.Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y"))`   It is a regex expression that is going into `matches` which should be a string

Comment: @cmirian most of the select helpers take string i.e. `contains`, `matches` ...

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this. Your data has empty spaces, that is why `is.na()` is not working:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
p %>% mutate(mr_daterd_fu1 = as.Date(mr_daterd_fu1,  format = '%d.%m.%Y'),
             fu1_date = if_else(date_contact=='', 
                               mr_daterd_fu1,
                               as.Date(date_contact,  format = '%d.%m.%Y', origin=mr_daterd_fu1)))
```

Output:

```
   date_contact mr_daterd_fu1   fu1_date
1                  2012-10-11 2012-10-11
2                        <NA>       <NA>
3                        <NA>       <NA>
4                        <NA>       <NA>
5    13.12.1994          <NA> 1994-12-13
6                        <NA>       <NA>
7    20.03.2012    2012-03-20 2012-03-20
8    25.08.1999          <NA> 1999-08-25
9    25.05.2012    2012-05-25 2012-05-25
10   19.10.2007          <NA> 2007-10-19
```